# Data inconsistency between SFMC and Sales Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

We are facing a strange problem with Synchronized Data from our Sales Cloud org.

Long story short, we are observing data inconsistency between Sales Cloud and the Synchronized Data Extensions. Sometimes, data is not updated on the synchronized data extensions even if it is on Sales Cloud. Even the LastModifiedDate is not the same between the two orgs (we've taken in consideration the timezones..).

We are aware of the fact that updating a `Formula` field does not update the `LastModifiedDate` of the record, and so it isn't picked up by the connector to supply the synchronized data extension. But we are facing the same problem with updates on other fields types as well..

We have been advised by the support to do manual refresh on all Data Sources **ONCE A WEEK**!! That doesn't make sense. I've even looked for some way to automate this in vain.

So, is anybody out there facing this problem? What are your recommendations/solutions?

PS: The poll schedule is 30 minutes. We've also tested 1 hour poll schedule and still have the problem.

Comment: You should not have to do a manual refresh weekly.  If you are having this issue with data that is not formula fields, then there might be other issues - such as modifying fields in SF after they have already been synced to the Marketing Cloud.  If the inconsistencies persist for days and only are corrected with a manual refresh, then support should engage the product team for further investigation.  
If you open a new case, I can help get it to the right team.

Answer (score 2):

A manual refresh should NOT be needed.  You will still want to ensure you are following the [best practices for data sync](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_implement_synchronized_data_sources_best_practices.htm&type=5).

If you are having this issue with data that is not stored in formula fields, then there could be other issues; such as modifying a field in Salesforce after you have already synced that field to the Marketing Cloud.

If the inconsistencies persist indefinitely and only are corrected with a manual refresh, then you would want to contact Marketing Cloud support to engage the product teams to investigate further.  Other options would be to disconnect to clean up all data sources, and re-sync objects and fields as needed.  That should alleviate any underlying issues.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jeremy. We are perfectly following data sync best practices. What do you mean by modifying a field in Salesforce after it already synced? Do you mean changing it's type? It lenght? As I said in the question, we've been advised by the support to do a manual refresh each week. And we agree that this doesn't make sense.. I'll create another case and try to challenge them..

Comment: @RachidMamai correct.  If you sync a field, then change the length, data type, name, or pick-list options, then this will cause similar issues.  

Refreshing in general should be a last resort.  I'll keep an eye out for your case and help keep it on track.  Thanks!