# What exactly triggers a record to be synchronised using Synchronised Data Extensions?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, integration, marketing-cloud-connect

What exactly triggers a record to be Synchronised using Synchronised Data Extensions?

When updating a few hundred Account records in Salesforce Core using a bulk file import using Workbench, this didn't update to the synchronised object in Salesforce Marketing Cloud automatically.

A complete Account object resync worked, so now we're curious about what exactly triggers a record to be synced in SFMC.

Answer (score 2):

I'll share what I've learned even though I'm sure there is more to it than this.

In a few words, I've found that a change in `LastModifiedDate` field is what triggers an update. But, you need to keep in mind that this field is not updated when a change occurs on a Formula field.

> Formula fields contained in Synchronized Data Sources update only when
> an update for another field on the object occurs. Formula fields don’t
> trigger a change to an object or update last modified date fields.
> When an update occurs, all synchronized formula fields for that object
> evaluate and update as necessary.

I've also faced some weird behaviour on some projects, I'll let you check this question I've asked before: [Data inconsistency between SFMC and Sales Cloud](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/292750/data-inconsistency-between-sfmc-and-sales-cloud). It does not surprise me at all that data still do not get synced with SFMC even if it theoretically should.

Reference: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_co_implement_synchronized_data_sources_best_practices.htm&type=5